# Is there any library to perform semantic role labeling in english?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, srl

I want to perform semantic role labelling on the user query in python. I searched online, but SRL is available for Portuguese. Is there any SRL library for english language ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

For searching open source library like this, you may want to refer to [Github](https://github.com) rather than Google.

Here is one I just found: https://github.com/luheng/deep_srl